# jquery .on('click') toggle css of this li element + call function same time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a number of lists, and want to toggle the css (background) of *this* li element when this is clicked launching a popup, the popup is working but cant get the on/off toggle to work which changes the background color of the item clicked.

here is the code below// its at the bottom the main part of the question- if any one can let me know how the above could be acheived that would be great + much appreciated

```
function displayChannels() {
    $.each(channel_list, function (index, channel) {
        //Make the code for the channel
        var code_channel = "<li><img src='" + channel._icon + "'/></li>";
        //Display it
        $("#channel-list").append(code_channel);
        //Open a list for the channel's program list
        var code_prog_list = "<ul class='channel_row'>";
        //Add each program in it as a li each time
        $.each(channel._programs, function (index, programme) {
            code_prog_list += "<li><div class='text-left'>" + "<h5>" + programme._hour + ":" + programme._minutes + "</h5>" + "<h6>" + programme._title + "</h6>" + "<p>" + programme._cat + " (" + programme._duree + "mn)" + "</p></div>" + "<div class='programme_icon'><img src='" + programme._icon + "'' alt=''/></div>" + "<div class='desc'>" + programme._desc + "</div>" + "<div class='star'>" + programme._star + "</div>";
            code_prog_list += "</li>";
            //$(this).children().width(programme._width);
            //$(this).css( "width", programme._width + 'px');
            //$( "#channel_row li").width(programme_width);
            //$(this).children('.channel_row li').width(programme._width);
        });
        //Close the list
        code_prog_list += "</ul>";
        //Display it
        $("#prog-grid").append(code_prog_list);
        $("#prog-grid ul").last().resizePrograms();
    });
    $("#loader").hide();
    scrollTime();
    $(".channel_row li").on("click", showPopup);
    $("#popup").on("click", function () {
        $("#popup").toggle(500);
    });
}
function showPopup() {
    var x = "<div id='close_button'></div>";
    $("#popup").html(x).show(500);
    $(this).children().css("background", "red");
}
```

Comment: use event.stopPropagation() of jquery to prevent the parent event from execution.http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and created a sample [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/LAMDK/15/)

As stated above, you just need to remove the other background colors and set the current one to what you want.  I changed your last function to this:

```
function showPopup() {
var x = "<div id='close_button'></div>";
$("#popup").html(x).show(500);
$(".channel_row li").children().css('background-color','');
$(this).children().css('background-color','red');
}
```

Comment: hey thankyou so much, this is working, i am slecting the children though- any ideas about selecting the actual li item itself instead of the two children divs inside? thankyou again for taking the time to respond

Comment: No problem, I updated the [FIDDLE (click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/LAMDK/16/) to what I think you mean and, as always, a 'marked as answer' is always appreciated :)

Comment: thanks again jason working fine, cant find the marked as answered?? and cant vote up your response as im new to stack overflow

Comment: No worries, glad i could help :) looks like it got marked as answered!

Comment: thanks! stack overflow is so good! incase your expertise is available for another question, i am trying to filter the .each() so that it only iterates over programs which have a category= 'jeu'... any ideas?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431921/jquery-each-filter-based-on-if-matches-category-type-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

Add a class, then remove and add as needed -

```
function showPopup() {
    var x = "<div id='close_button'></div>";
    $("#popup").html(x).show(500);
    $('li').removeClass('redClass'); // remove those with the class first
    $(this).children().addClass('redClass'); // add the class to the current selected
}
```

Comment: thankyou thats great, however how can it toggle so that when another li is clicked that li changes and the other li return to original state? thankyou for taking the time to respond

Comment: The two lines of code do just that - when an li is clicked all of the li's are cleared first (returning to original state), then the one selected is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the handy toggleClass function on the LI itself and leave CSS to figure out how to handle the background colors?

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmJy3/

```
$(this).toggleClass("onecolor");
```

[.toggleClass() - JQuery API Reference](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)