# jquery .each() filter based on if matches category type in xml

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the below function to display each program collected in the previous function.

Its working fine, I want to be able ot refine it so that when a button is clicked it does the each(). for only those programs which have a certain category eg 'Jeu'

Any ideas on how I can refine this each() ?

```
function displayChannels()
{
    $.each(channel_list, function(index, channel) {
        //Make the code for the channel
        var code_channel = "<li>"
        +"<img src='"+channel._icon+"' alt='"+channel._name+"' title='"+channel._name+"'/>"
        +"<p>"+channel._name+"</p>"
        +"</li>";
        //Display it
        $("#channel-list").append(code_channel);

        //Open a list for the channel's program list
        var code_prog_list = "<ul class='channel_row'>";
        //Add each program in it as a li each time

 // DO I NEED TO PUT A FILTER HERE FOR PROGRAMS WHICH MATCH THE CATEGORY 'JEU'
        $.each(channel._programs, function( index, programme ) {
            code_prog_list+="<div class='program'>"
            +"<div class='program_bg'><img src='"+programme._img+"' alt=' '/></div>"
            +"<div class='programInner'>"
            +"<div class='channelIcon'><img src='logos/logo"+programme._icon+".png'/></div>"
            +"<div class='textContainer'><h4>"+programme._title+"</h4>"
            +"<strong><p>"+programme._hour+":"+programme._minutes+"</strong> | "+programme._cat+" ("+programme._duree+"mn)"+"</p></div>" // end of text container
            +"</div>"// end of programInner
            +"<div class='desc'>"+programme._desc+"</div>"
            +"</div>"; // end of div program 
        });

        //Display it
        $("#main").append(code_prog_list);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use an `if` statement? `if (channel._category == 'JEU') { ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the category is 'JEU' inside the function and return true:

```
if(programme._cat !== 'JEU') {
    return true;
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for jQuery.each,

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So basically by returning true in the anonymous function inside `.each` you're skipping programmes that don't have 'JEU' as their category.

Comment: YES it worked!!!!!!! so good thanks! smart idea it tricks the each into skipping to the next thanks raibaz